# Distributed file systems

Tags: distributed-filesystems

I need to implement a distributed storage system for a set of nodes(devices) connected in a mesh network.

So what basically my design goals are:

1. The storage system should be capable of handling dynamic entry and exit of nodes.
2. Replication (for fault tolerance).

For this i am thinking of using a Distributed file system. Every node could access data in the other nodes in a transparent manner.

Are there some simple, easily pluggable opensource implementations?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

[OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org/) is a well supported, cross platform distributed file system solution used widely, which can do all of what you said.

Answer (score 3):

[Ceph](http://ceph.newdream.net/), when it reaches production quality, might be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

OpenAFS is quite good.  It also allows for a service pool so that a disconnected node still has a copy of their data.  i.e. you work on your laptop which is an AFS node, but, files that are in your distributed storage modified recently still have a local copy.  When you reconnect, those modified files are then resynced.

GlusterFS/Lustre is another decent one.  I had some performance problems with GlusterFS on write-heavy content, but, it worked very well.

http://www.cleversafe.org/dispersed-storage/  is another possible solution.

http://danga.com/mogilefs/ if you don't require a posix compliant filesystem

Answer (score 1):

If you need open source and fault-tolerant distributed file system then you can use [MooseFS](https://moosefs.com/). You can install it easily for example on Ubuntu.